# My PHP contact form keeps giving error

Tags: php, contact-form

Following is my code of contact form. Fields are ok but it is not sending mail and gives error message "Error sending message". I checked with the `samplemail.php` file from [this link](http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-script-not-sending-email.html) and it is working well, but if I use the same code for my website replacing the values, it doesn't work.

 
index.html

```
<form id="contact-valid-form" class="form-style" action="contact.php" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="text-field form-control field-validation required" data-validation-type="string" id="form-name" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" />
        <i class="form-icon fa fa-user"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="text-field form-control field-validation required" data-validation-type="email" id="form-email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" />
    <i class="form-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea placeholder="Message..." class="form-control field-validation required" name="message"></textarea>
        <i class="form-icon fa fa-comment"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group submit">
        <span class="form-loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>   
</form>
```

in contact.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: ' . $_POST['email']; 
$to  = 'myemail@mail.com'; 
$subject = 'subject';


$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message";
if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {

        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Success</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Error sending message</p>'; 
    } 


} else {
    echo '<p>fill the form</p>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: I am getting the "Error sending message" from the else statement @sulthan-allaudeen

Comment: I am getting `success`  Are you filling all the fields ?

Comment: @sulthan-allaudeen yes I am filling all the fields

Comment: I think mail server is not configured.

Comment: Are you getting mail?

Comment: @WisdmLabs as I said above, I used a contact sample form in the link above to test my mail server and it works OK, it sends message. But my contact form does not

Comment: Remove From field from the mail() function, then try.

Comment: i can try in my localhost show me 'Success' message!!

Answer (score 0):

The generic error message is not adding more Information. Can you please add the below code in your else part ? This should provide the last failure.

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Success</p>';
} else { 
    print_r(error_get_last()); 
}
```

Comment: I get a blank screen after clicking on submit. Cannot see any error message

Comment: May be i suggest the attempts: 1) Check the configuration of smpt in your ini file. 2) Check if anonymous emails are allowed from your Server. 3) Try to hardcode the values in the mail command and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

I run your code in my browser.It works properly..It prints message 'Success' because mail() function returns 1.

Comment: add $header instead of $body


<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>